# Make Microsoft-Graph API calls without registering the app

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

This is NOT a code related question. But a question on auth while accessing Microsoft Graph.

I have a small nodeJS code that will access my own files on one drive and pull some data from an excel spreadsheet. This app is just my own, for automating a task. Is it possible for nodeJS code to access Microsoft Graph APIs without having to register this app and get admin approval?

I have a work account. My admin would not approve an app that is not going to help my organization.

Answer (score 4):

It's determined by what kind of your account.

- If your account is a work/school account, which is managed by your organization, you must register the application/create servicePrincipal in your organization tenant to call Microsoft Graph API. Because all company data, including your account data, is managed by your organization, not yourself.
- If your account is a personal account, Microsoft Live Account, you can use Microsoft app registration portal for personal identity platform: https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/. It's managed by your own personal account.

Comment: I have a work account. :( My admin would not approve an app that is not going to help my organization.

Comment: That's basically your organisation saying that you can't make your app then. Ultimately it's up to the admin there.

Comment: Nice way to strangle innovation by blocking access to data that you already have permission for but only on another interface. Good work Microsoft.